# Lex/Yacc based C parser: why unterminated string literal is not diagnosed?

Tags: regex, bison, flex-lexer, yacc, lex

I built C parser from Lex/Flex & YACC/Bison grammars ([1](https://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y.html), [2](https://gist.github.com/codebrainz/2933703)) as:

```
$ flex c.l && yacc -d c.y && gcc lex.yy.c y.tab.c -o c
```

and then tested on this C code:

```
char* s = "xxx;
```

which is expected to produce `missing terminating " character` (or `syntax error`) diagnostics.
However, it doesn't:

```
$ ./c t1.c
char* s = xxx;
```

Why? How to fix it?

Note: The `STRING_LITERAL` is defined in lex specification as:

```
L?\"(\\.|[^\\"])*\"     { count(); return(STRING_LITERAL); }
```

Here we see the `[^\\"]` part, which represents the "except the double-quote ", backslash , or new-line character" (C11, 6.4.5 String literals, 1) and the `\\.` part, which (incorrectly?) represents the `escape-sequence` (C11, 6.4.4.4 Character constants, 1). -- end note

UPD: Fix: The `STRING_LITERAL` is defined in lex specification as:

```
L?\"(\\.|[^\\"\n])*\"   { count(); return(STRING_LITERAL); }
```

Comment: Why did you remove the `\n` from `[^\\"\n]`? Your version `[^\\"]` does not represent "except double-quote, backslash or new-line character" because it accepts a new-line character. It's important to know that `[^...]` will match a newline unless newline is explicitly mentioned. `.` doesn't match newline, but that's part of the definition of `.`, not some kind of unmentioned general rule.

Comment: Also, it's not necessary (in this context) to match a complete escape sequence. It's only necessary to match an escape sequence which might otherwise be confused with a string literal metacharacter, and all such cases involve the single character immediately following the backslash. So `\\.` does the trick, except that it assumes that splices have already been removed from the source text. If splices haven't been removed, then a string literal may include a splice and the pattern should be `\\(?s:.)`, which causes the `.` to match anything, including  a newline character.

Comment: @rici Re: "`\n`": lex specification in [1](https://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-l.html) has no `\n`. Fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lexer you link has a rule:

```
.           { /* Add code to complain about unmatched characters */ }
```

so when it sees an unmatched `"`, it will silently ignore it.  If you add code here to complain about the character, you'll see that.

If you want a syntax error, you could have this action just `return *yytext;`

Note that your `STRING_LITERAL` pattern will match strings that contain embedded newlines, so if you have a mismatched `"` in a larger program wity another string later, it will be recognized as a long string with embedded newlines.  This will likely lead to poor error reporting, since the error would be reported after the bug string rather than where it starts, making it hard for a user to debug.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please elaborate about the `.` rule? Why the lexer has this rule? Is it required to have this rule? Note: at this point I have only basic knowledge of lex. Note that [lex specification by Jutta Degener](https://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-l.html) has `. { /* ignore bad characters */ }`. Note: you can diff it with [c99.l](https://gist.github.com/codebrainz/2933703). There are notable differences.

Comment: `.` is a patten that matches any single character except newline.  You can use it in a pattern.  As to why that lexer uses it in that way, I have no idea.